# Export table to csv from beeline(cli)

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix, command-line-interface

I want to: Export table from a jdbc:oracle database to a comma delimited csv file from beeline(CLI)  
I have tried bcp without success.  
I have tried -beeline> bcp "select * from db_name.table_name" queryout "/home/feed/data/inventory.csv";  
It gives error as invalid sql statement.  
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the steps/code of what you have attempted so far..

Comment: You might just need to add a semicolon `;` to the end of your query.

Comment: Tried giving the command within quotes - 'bcp "select * from db_name.table_name" queryout "/home/feed/data/inventory.csv"';   It gives the error - Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

Comment: try something basic such as "select 1 + 1;"

Comment: @JohnC - It gives the error - Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

Comment: Is this something which does not work from a beeline (cli) ?

Comment: It actually works if i just give - select * from db.table_name;

Comment: Is this something to do with beeline?
When i login it gives the error to beeline - READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE are the only valid transaction levels.

Answer (score 3):

While connecting to Beeline you can specify, `--ouputformat=[table/vertical/csv/tsv/dsv/csv2/tsv2]`. More info on separated value output formats can be found here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Separated-ValueOutputFormats